# Как сделать бесконечный цикл в cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, faq

Нужно бесконечно повторять некую команду. как это реализовать в командной строке?

Comment: `:10 goto 10` уже не работает?

Comment: @vp_arth, а ответ прочитать?

Comment: Не всё же сразу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Если речь идёт непосредственно о командной строке

то стоит воспользоваться циклом `for`:

```
for /l %q in (0) do echo Loop
```

## Если же речь о bat-файле

в предыдущей команде можно удвоить знак процента:

```
for /l %%q in (0) do echo Loop
```

но лучше воспользоваться меткой и `goto`:

```
:loop
echo Loop
goto loop
```