# как в bat файле сделать так, чтобы после выполнения bat файл не закрывался

Tags: bat

Как в bat файле сделать так, чтобы после выполнения bat файл не закрывался?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать бесконечный цикл в cmd?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631193/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b2-cmd)

Answer (score 6):

Можно последней строкой поместить что-то из этого:

```
pause
```

```
cmd
```

Либо запускать так:

```
cmd /k smth.bat
```

или даже так (если он иногда делает `exit`):

```
cmd /k cmd /c smth.bat
```

Comment: проблема: это пишет Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

Comment: А чем не устраивает?

Comment: Скачай и открой этот файл: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2COSiDn1YVGTEtwSHZiSUZDOGc/view

Comment: @LGPvS если нужно избавиться от сообщения про клавишу, *pause >nul*

Comment: всё равно закрывается

Comment: @VadimTagil, кажется, это тебе)

Comment: да если бы еще понимать, что автор хочет сделать... судя по примеру по ссылке, он решает какую-то совершенно другую задачу

Comment: @VadimTagil, пишет очередной антивирус на батниках...

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё вариант:

```
REM do something...
echo This is my BAT-file

@cmd /K
```

Т.е., выполняем то, что требуется, а в конце по-тихому (с префиксом `@`) вызываем `cmd /K`. Так не напишет в конце а-ля "для продолжения нажмите...", а просто отобразит приглашение командной строки.

А ещё можно так:

```
REM do something...
echo This is my BAT-file

@pause > nul
```

Так выход будет по нажатию любой клавиши, но тоже в конце ничего не напишет.